# Dúvida sobre menu dropdown WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress, dropdown

Estou desenvolvendo um site no ***wordpress*** e no menu possuo um item que é `dropdown` como segue o exemplo:

- HOME
- CURSOS

  - CURSO1
  - CURSO2
- SOBRE

Porém eu queria que o usuário não fosse redirecionado para outra página se ele clicasse sem querer em CURSOS, ao invés de clicar em um dos submenus.

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependendo do tema do seu Wordpress isso é personalizável no próprio menu de customização do tema.

Mas deixando isso de lado, você pode usar uma das seguintes alternativas:

1. Alterar o link do item `Cursos`, que está no menu, para redirecionar p/ a URL `#`, assim ao clicar ele não será redirecionado p/ nenhum outro link
2. Adicionar uma classe específica p/ esse item do menu, e usar algum [código em jQuery](http://wpgarage.com/code-snippets/how-to-remove-the-link-to-parent-pages-when-using-wp_list_pages-in-wordpress-navigation/) ou um [equivalente em PHP](https://bavotasan.com/2009/how-to-remove-the-links-to-parent-pages-in-the-wordpress-page-list/) p/ remover links
3. Usar o plugin ["Disable Parent Menu Link"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-disable-parent-menu-link/) ou criar um próprio, com funcionalidade parecida
4. Definir o `href` dos itens 'não-clicáveis' como `javascript:void(0)`

Comment: Excelente, muito obrigado